# <xsl:when test="//..."> syntax

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to debug an existing XSLT file and have the following elements

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="//j:Node_A/j:Node_B/j:Node_c">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//j:Node_A/j:Node_B/j:Node_c />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="NoMatch" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

As I understand the test statement it is looking for a structure like the following in the XML and when the structure is found applies the template.

```
  <node_a>
    <node_b>
      <node_c>
          DATA
      </node_c>
    </node_b>
  </node_a>
```

What I don't understand is the meaning of the `//`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an XPath question.

The "//" indicates "not starting at root"

`/blam/hoot/kapow` only matches if the root node is blam.

`//blam/hoot/kapow`  matches if there is a node pattern of blam containing a hoot containing a kapow.

The second test will match the blam/hoot/kapow in this:

```
<schmar>
   <blam>
     <hoot>
       <kapow>
       </kapow>
     </hoot>
   </blam>
</schmar>
```

The first test will not match in the xml above.

Answer (score 2):

The precise definition of `//` in XPath is that it is shorthand for

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/
```

*including* the leading and trailing slashes.  The path `a//b` is effectively the union of `a/b`, `a/*/b`, `a/*/*/b`, etc. for any number of repetitions of `/*`

In practice this means you can use it when you want to look for descendant nodes at any level rather than just immediate children, e.g. `/node_a//node_c`.

Answer (score 1):

`//` represents the `descendant::` or `descendant-or-self::` axis in XPath. It should be followed by a *node test* which can be:

- qualified name of an element. Ex: //j:node_a (matches all descendant `node_a` elements in the namespace represented by the prexif `j` - same as `//descendant-or-self::j:node_a`)
- an `*` which represents *any* element. Ex: //* (matches all descendant *elements* - same as `//descendant-or-self::*`)
- text(), processing-instruction() or comment(). Ex: //text() (matches all descendant *text nodes* - same as `//descendant-or-self::text()`)
- another axis. Ex: `//@*` (matches all attributes - same as `//attribute::*`)

You can use it anywhere inside the XPath expression to skip levels in a tree. For example:

```
//j:Node_A//j:Node_c
```

will match all `Node_c` elements which have a `Node_A` ancestor.

Note that XPath expressions are case sensitive: `Node_a` != `Node_A` != `node_a`.

Your XSLT selects elements which are prefixed. It should also have a declaration somewhere (normally in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element) which associates that prefix with a namespace for your expressions to work.